# Why the same MacMini provides different MAC addresses for different OS?

Tags: ethernet, mac-address

I run MacOS and CoreOS Linux on the same MacMini. The same network interface has MAC f0:18:98:ea:7f:9f under MacOS and has MAC 38:f9:d3:16:96:ce under CoreOS. First one is printed on a box of this MacMini, second one isn't.

Why does it have two different MAC?

MacMini 2018 gen, with T2 chip.

Answer (score 2):

MAC addresses are assigned to network interfaces, not to computers. The F0:98:18 address is for the wireless card, and the 38:F9:D3 address is for the wired Ethernet interface.

Comment: Nope, WiFi interface has different MAC.